# Got a lot of crazy traffic to multicast addresses

Tags: networking

On one of my external hostet vservers I got a lot of traffic to multicast addresses (SRC-IP Changed)

```
22:09:38.804122 IP 1.2.3.4.51960 > 255.255.255.255.6112: UDP, length 128

22:15:02.787315 IP 4.5.6.7.17500 > 255.255.255.255.17500: UDP, length 167

22:15:02.791780 IP 4.5.6.7.17500 > 109.75.188.255.17500: UDP, length 167
```

Could anybody tell me, what this is?

Comment: 109.75.188.255 is not a multicast address.  It could be a broadcast to the subnet that your virtual server is in.  Is your server's subnet 109.75.188.0/24?

Comment: 255.255.255.255 also is a broadcast address.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing suspicious about these packets.  If they were in any way malicious you couldn't tell it from this list alone.

You'd have to have a deeper look.   E.g. you could analyze the situation with [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark).  It often recognizes the application protocols (i.e. what's inside e.g. the packets) and even describes the meaning of the individual packets with regard to the protocol.